# How to set a condition in IIS UrlRewrite to check if the URL is valid

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, redirect, umbraco7

I have an issue with setting an condition for my IIS URLRewrite to set it so when the entered url is not valid then it takes you to a set url. for instance you type url: example.local/current_work that would be a valid url so it shows the page however for url : example.local/this_doesnt_exist it will redirect you back to the example.local/current_work etc...

Hope I am clear on this one.

```
<rewrite>
 <rules>
  <rule name="Test" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url="^scottishtrunkroadsse.amey.local/([_0-9a-z-]+)" negate="false"/>
     <conditions>
         <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
         <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
     </conditions>
   <action type="Redirect" url="current-works/" />
  </rule>
 </rules>
<rewrite>
```

Thank you for any help.

I am using an Umbraco website but I don't think that change anything as the IIS url should be working in the same way.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you want to create redirect  `example.local/this_doesnt_exist` to `example.local/current_work`. Only for this url? Or do you have list of non existent urls?

Comment: Just for this URL , thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This rule will redirect `example.local/this_doesnt_exist` to `example.local/current_work`:

```
<rule name="Test" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url="^this_doesnt_exist$" />
   <action type="Redirect" url="/current_work" />
</rule>
```

Comment: Great that works but I meant to say to redirect to example.loca/current_work from any invalid url not just "this_doesnt_exist". Sorry my bad

Comment: Hmm, may be it is better for you, just to set custom 404 page 
        `<httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
            <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
            <error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/current_work" responseMode="Redirect" />
        </httpErrors>`

Comment: Thanks Victor,  however do you think it is possible to do it just purely by the IIS url rewrite? Apreciate your help. thanks

Comment: It is not possible purely with URL rewrite